# ERESOLVE could not resolve

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, npm, frontend, react-bootstrap

[**When I tried installing bootstrap these errors came how to resolve these?**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpdbV.png)

Comment: Please always post errors / error trace stack as text, not as picture

Answer (score 0):

You use react 18.2, but you need React 16.x

Comment: Thanks. I fear that once the new gen npm comes out maybe the older one becomes of no use. So i didnt reduced the npm version rather did --force.  and things going normal so far